DOCPLEX Job Shop Scheduling In With Downtime
I am scheduling tasks (audits) to machines (auditors) with machine skills and planned downtime as considerations. I am using the docplex package in Python and following this tutorial.
The model solves when I do not add the calendar/breaks as constraints but I get infeasible with the break constraint. I have been going over this for two weeks now and am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Here is my complete code:
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel, INTERVAL_MIN, CpoStepFunction
import types
import pandas as pd

TIME_H = 30
df_workers = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['Joe', 'Jack', 'Jim']}).set_index(['id'])

df_tasks = pd.DataFrame({
'id': ['audit1', 'audit2', 'audit3', 'audit4', 'audit5', 'audit6', 'audit7', 'audit8', 'audit9', 'audit10'],
'duration': [1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5, 5]}).set_index(['id'])

df_precedences = pd.DataFrame({'before': ['audit1'],
                               'after':  ['audit2']})

df_skills = pd.DataFrame({
    'task': ['audit1', 'audit2', 'audit3', 'audit4', 'audit5', 'audit6', 'audit7', 'audit8', 'audit9', 'audit10',
             'audit1', 'audit2', 'audit3', 'audit4', 'audit5', 'audit6', 'audit7', 'audit8', 'audit9', 'audit10',
             'audit1', 'audit2', 'audit3', 'audit4', 'audit5', 'audit6', 'audit7', 'audit8', 'audit9', 'audit10'],
    'worker': ['Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe', 'Joe',
               'Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack','Jack',
               'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim'],
    'skill': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
              0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]}).set_index(['task', 'worker'])

worker_task_pairs = df_skills[df_skills['skill'] == 1].reset_index()[['task', 'worker']]

Worker = {}
for i in range(len(worker_task_pairs)):
    t = worker_task_pairs.loc[i][0]
    w = worker_task_pairs.loc[i][1]
    Worker[t] = w


df_worker_availability = {
 'Joe' :  [(0, 2)],
 'Jim' :  [(8, 9)],
 'Jack':  [(2, 3)],
}

from collections import namedtuple

Break = namedtuple('Break', ['start', 'end'])
Calendar = {}
mymax = max(max(v for k,v in df_worker_availability[w]) for w in df_workers.reset_index().values.flatten())

for w in df_workers.reset_index().values.flatten():
    step = CpoStepFunction()
    step.set_value(0, mymax, 1)
    for b in df_worker_availability[w]:
        t = Break(*b)
        step.set_value(t.start, t.end, 0)
    Calendar[w] = step



df_parameters = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['nbHouses', 'deadline'],
                              'value': [1, TIME_H]}).set_index(['name'])

NB_HOUSES = df_parameters.value['nbHouses']
DEADLINE = df_parameters.value['deadline']
outputs = {}

# Create model
mdl = CpoModel()

# Initialize model variable sets
total_skill = 0    # Expression computing total of skills
worker_tasks = {}  # Tasks (interval variables) assigned to a each worker
desc = dict()      # Map retrieving task from interval variable


# Utility function
def make_schedule_horizon(loc, deadline):   
    tasks = {}   
    tasks = {t:mdl.interval_var(size=task.duration,
                end=(INTERVAL_MIN, deadline), 
                #intensity = Calendar[Worker[t]],
                name='Audit' + str(loc) + '-' + t) 
                for t, task in df_tasks.iterrows()}    
    

    for i, precedence in df_precedences.iterrows():
        mdl.add(mdl.end_before_start(tasks[precedence.before], tasks[precedence.after]))


    global total_skill
    for t, task in df_tasks.iterrows():
        allocs = []
        for w, worker in df_workers.iterrows():
            if df_skills.skill[t, w] > 0:
                wt = mdl.interval_var(
                    optional=True, 
                    intensity = Calendar[Worker[t]],
                    name="{}-{}({})".format(loc, t, w), )


                if (w not in worker_tasks):
                    worker_tasks[w] = []
                worker_tasks[w].append(wt)
                allocs.append(wt)
                total_skill += (df_skills.skill[t, w] * mdl.presence_of(wt))
                desc[wt] = t

        try:
            mdl.add(mdl.alternative(tasks[t], allocs))
        except:
            pass



for h in range(NB_HOUSES): # Make schedule horizons
    make_schedule_horizon(h, DEADLINE)


for w, worker in df_workers.iterrows(): # Avoid overlapping between tasks of each worker
    mdl.add(mdl.no_overlap(worker_tasks[w]))
        
# add availability
for interval_var, task  in desc.items():
    mdl.add(mdl.forbid_start(interval_var, Calendar[Worker[task]]))
    mdl.add(mdl.forbid_end(interval_var, Calendar[Worker[task]]))

    
# KPIs
makespan = mdl.max([mdl.end_of(task) for task in worker_tasks[w] for w, workers in df_workers.iterrows()])
mdl.add_kpi(makespan, 'makespan')
mdl.add_kpi(total_skill, 'total_skill')

# Maximize total of skills
mdl.add(mdl.minimize(makespan))
mdl.print_information()
print("Solving model....")
msol = mdl.solve(TimeLimit=60, log_output=True, )
print("Solution: ")
msol.print_solution()

# Export solution
data = []
if msol:
    for w, worker in df_workers.iterrows():
        for t in worker_tasks[w]:
            wt = msol.get_var_solution(t)
            if wt.is_present():
                data.append([wt.get_name(), desc[t], w, wt.get_start(), wt.get_end()]);

df_schedule = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'audit', 'auditor', 'start', 'end'])
outputs['schedule'] = df_schedule
print(df_schedule)

kpis = []
if msol:
    kpis.append(['makespan', msol.get_value('makespan')])
    kpis.append(['total_skill', msol.get_value('total_skill')])

df_kpis = pd.DataFrame(data=kpis, columns=['name', 'value'])
outputs['kpis'] = df_kpis
print(df_kpis)

import docplex.cp.utils_visu as visu
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 25, 5

# Draw solution
if msol and visu.is_visu_enabled():
    visu.timeline('Solution SchedOptional', 0, DEADLINE)
    for w, worker in df_workers.iterrows():
        visu.sequence(name=w)
        for t in worker_tasks[w]:
            wt = msol.get_var_solution(t)
            if wt.is_present():
                if df_skills.skill[desc[t], w] == max(df_skills.skill[desc[t], w2] for w2, worker2 in df_workers.iterrows()):
                    # Green-like color when task is using the most skilled worker
                    color = 'lightgreen'
                else:
                    # Red-like color when task does not use the most skilled worker
                    color = 'salmon'
                visu.interval(wt, color, wt.get_name())
    visu.show()


You can find and print the conflict by calling:
print(mdl.refine_conflict())
You will see that Joe has 2 tasks to do of duration 1 and 7, and he only has 7 available slots.
